# Ho to normalize my TV audio to M-AUDIO speakers?

Tags: speakers, equalization, television, normalize

I don't know if this is the best site to ask it for.

I have `RCA` audio output from my **Samsung TV** to **M-AUDIO** speakers, the sound is perfect if I play PlayStation and other consolles games, but it's totally worse for movies in general (Netflix, Prime Video, MKV files, etc.)

Basically I have moments where I cannot hear actor voices alterned to moments where explosions or music are too high and I'm forced to adjust the volume, continuously.

This ruins my evenings.

Does exists some way to normalize audio from my TV?

I can use also digital audio if needed or use some tool (i suppose to normalize audio) between my **Samsung TV** and **M-AUDIO** speakers.

I'm not a sound engineer so I just suppose it's a normalization problem, so how can I do to maybe lower this problem?

Comment: You are not looking for 'normalisation' but 'compression' or 'limiting'. [idk why but for some reason the entire interwebz seems to think that's what normalisation does… it doesn't :\  …& no, this is the wrong site for consumer audio, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the manual for your TV to see if it has DRC (Dynamic Range Compression) or "night mode".  This feature reduces the difference between the loudest and quietest parts so the volume level is more even.

Comment: Thank you, I've found the option "Night mode"